# How can I generate a vBulletin password salt for the md5 hash while importing user data?

Tags: passwords, password-protection, salt, vbulletin

I'm transferring users from my old database to a vBulletin database.

I want a script to do this as it'll take forever otherwise.

I have all the user's passwords stored just like md5(password)

But of course, this doesn't work with vBulletin due to salts etc.

So my code is this:

```
<?Php
mydatabase_connect();
$select=mysql_query("SELECT * from `users`");
while($user=mysql_fetch_array($select)) {

    forum_connect();
    $check=mysql_query("SELECT * from `user` where `username` = '{$user[username]}'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($check)>="1") {
        echo "fail";
        }else{
        $insert=mysql_query("INSERT into `user` SET `username` = '{$user[username]}', `password` = '{$user[password]}', `email` = '{$user[email]}'");
        if($insert) {
            echo 'success';
            }else{
            echo 'fail';
        }
    }
    mydatabase_connect();
}
?>
```

How would I change it to work with vBulletin - so I can set a vBulletin user.`password` field and vBulletin user.`salt` correctly. Bearing in mind that my $user[password] or `users`.`password` is stored as an md5 hash of their real, text password.

Thanks!

Comment: Because of the extraordinarily weak pasword hashing scheme used by vbulletin and other holes in it, I think you should assume that all those passwords were compromised, and force all users to upgrade their passwords.  Given how bad the pracices seem to have been, you may well want to switch to forum software written by people who know and care a lot more about security.  See e.g. [vBulletin password hack fuels fears of serious Internet-wide 0-day attacks | Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/11/vbulletin-password-hack-fuels-fears-of-serious-internet-wide-0-day-attacks/)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this answer is too late, but you should be able to automatically transfer your passwords into vBulletin.

vBulletin generates its hashes this way:

```
$hash = md5(md5($plaintext) . $salt);
```

So, to transfer the users over, do roughly the following:

```
$salt = /* generate salt */;
$vb_hash = md5($your_old_hash . $salt);
```

To make it easy on yourself, use vBulletin's salt generation method. It's in the `vB_DataManager_User` class.

Answer (score 1):

If your old system used unsalted hashes, and vBulletin uses salted ones, then if you want users to keep their passwords you will have to modify vBulletin to use unsalted ones too. I'm not familiar with the vBulletin code, but if each user has their own salt value, perhaps just setting this to an empty string will suffice.

Failing that, write a page to enable a user to transition to the new system. You can direct users to a page when their login fails, and it would check their credentials against the old system, and create a new salt and hash for the new system.

Comment: Each user does have their own salt value, I would imagine option two is the safest/best choice here. The first solution also means you'll be carrying code changes through every update, which while not necessarily a major problem, poses its own set of challenges over time.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
md5(md5(passowrd).salt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted the process I used to transfer the user information from an existing database to the vbulletin database. It uses database queries entered through the MySQL command line client, no PHP processing is required.

It works for the scenario outlined: that passwords in the existing database were stored using `md5(password)`.

Both databases are on the same server, vBulletin 4.x

Three stored functions will be created:

```
vbulletin.userTitle() // Convert user type from current db to a user title

vbulletin.groupId() // Convert current user type into permission group ID

vbulletin.randomSalt() // Create salt using same approach as used by vbulletin
```

---

Log in through the MySQL client:
  `mysql --user=xxx -p vbulletin`

Create the stored functions:

```
  delimiter //
  CREATE FUNCTION vbulletin.userTitle(mtype VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS CHAR(250)
  NO SQL

  BEGIN
    DECLARE userTypeTitle CHAR(250) DEFAULT "";

    CASE mtype
      WHEN 'user' THEN SET userTypeTitle = 'Member';
      WHEN 'admin' THEN SET userTypeTitle = 'Administrator';
      WHEN 'moderator' THEN SET userTypeTitle = 'Regional Moderator';
      ELSE
        SET userTypeTitle = 'Member';
    END CASE;

  RETURN userTypeTitle;
  END//

  CREATE FUNCTION vbulletin.groupId(mtype VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS smallint(5)
  NO SQL

  BEGIN
    DECLARE groupTypeId smallint(5) DEFAULT 0;

    CASE mtype
      WHEN 'user' THEN SET groupTypeId = 2;
      WHEN 'admin' THEN SET groupTypeId = 6;
      WHEN 'moderator' THEN SET groupTypeId = 11;
      ELSE
         SET groupTypeId = 12;
    END CASE;

  RETURN groupTypeId;
  END//

  CREATE FUNCTION vbulletin.randomSalt()
  RETURNS CHAR(30)
  READS SQL DATA

  BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE rn1 CHAR;
    DECLARE saltout VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT "";

    WHILE count<30 DO
      SET count = count+1;
      SET rn1 = CHAR(FLOOR(33 + (RAND() * 93)));
      SELECT CONCAT(saltout, rn1) INTO saltout;
    END WHILE;

  RETURN saltout;
  END//
  delimiter ;
```

---

Back up the databases before transferring the user information.

The vbulletin database has all of the information used during set up and testing, so empty the three tables that we'll be updating.

```
  TRUNCATE `vbulletin`.`user`;
  TRUNCATE `vbulletin`.`userfield`;
  TRUNCATE `vbulletin`.`usertextfield`;
```

---

Modify the following queries to use your existing database and it's related fields.

Fill the main user table.
The salt is generated via the stored function for each row in the existing user table.
The hashed password from the existing database is hashed with the salt when it is inserted into the vbulletin database like this:
`MD5(current_hashed_password + new_salt)`

Main query:

```
  INSERT INTO `vbulletin`.`user` (
  `userid`, `username`, `salt`, `password`, `email`, `passworddate`, `styleid`, `showvbcode`, `joindate`, `lastvisit`, `lastactivity`, `reputationlevelid`, `timezoneoffset`, `usergroupid`, `usertitle`
  )
  SELECT
  `current_userid`, `current_username`, vbulletin.randomSalt() as new_salt, MD5(current_hashed_password + new_salt), `current_email`, CURDATE(), 5, 2, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 5, 0, vbulletin.groupId(current_type), vbulletin.userTitle(current_type)
   from `current_database`.`user`;
```

---

The following queries add default entries for each user.

If you've added any customized profile fields, you'll want to transfer that information into the userfield table:

```
  INSERT INTO `vbulletin`.`userfield` (
  `userid`, `field5`, `field6`
  )
  SELECT
  `current_userid`, `firstname`, `lastname`
   from `current_database`.`user`;


  INSERT INTO `vbulletin`.`usertextfield` (
  `userid`
  )
  SELECT `current_userid`
   from `current_database`.`user`;
```

---

Set the reputation level for your admin group users:

```
  UPDATE `vbulletin`.`user` SET `reputationlevelid` = 1 WHERE `usergroupid` = 6;
```

Remove the stored functions, they won't be used again:

```
  DROP FUNCTION vbulletin.userTitle;
  DROP FUNCTION vbulletin.groupId;
  DROP FUNCTION vbulletin.randomSalt;
```